# Snap.svg animation jumping after completion

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

I'm just dipping my feet into the world of SVGs and am trying to wrap my head around Snap.svg. Just to play around I'm trying to animate an svg of a trash can using Element.hover but after the animation completes the lid is jumping up where it shouldn't be.

I'm finding the Snap.svg documentation to be severely lacking and I've looked at the Raphael.js documentation as well (since they're written by the same author) but I'm not sure if I'm doing something incorrectly or not.

Here's my javascript:

```
var trashContainer = Snap('#trash'),
    trashLid       = trashContainer.select('#lid');

trashContainer.hover(
    function() {
        trashLid.animate({transform: 't0,-5'}, 1000, mina.elastic);
    },
    function() {
        trashLid.animate({transform: 't0,0'}, 500, mina.bounce);
    }
);
```

And here is a jsfiddle that illustrates the problem (try hovering numerous times): http://jsfiddle.net/jackmparker/py1bkv1c/11/

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The problem is you have 2 animations that will conflict. You hover over the div, and a hover over starts. Then you hover out and the hover reverts back. However, where was the animation when you started to hover back ? You need to think about the logic of what you actually want to happen when mid animation and another hover event happens. Do you want to queue them up, should the timing be different if it only has to return half the distance ? Its more fiddly than one realises, but once you nail the logic, writing the handlers will be easier.

Comment: @Ian I appreciate the response but I'm still not seeing what you're alluding to. Would you mind setting up a jsfiddle with an example of something similar that works the way you've explained?

Comment: For example, the first animation is 1000ms long. Lets say you hover out after 100ms, the hover out animation starts which is 500ms long. There is obviously a conflict there no ? You will probably notice if you leave at least 1000ms before a hoverout it will work correctly highlighting this. I may be wrong, but it looks like thats what is happening.

Comment: @Ian I think I understand where you're going with that now, but I'm not sure that's a real concern. This is (from my understanding) much like using jQuery's .hover() method and those kind of precautions aren't needed in that situation. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the complexity but your suggestion sounds to me more like writing this code from scratch rather than utilizing the Snap.svg library. Again, if you can set up a jsfiddle with what you're proposing, I'm sure it would make a lot more sense. As always, thanks for the response.

Comment: I'm not proposing anything, just highlighting where I would expect the problem to be.